# plot highlighting

Tags: javascript, css, image

for example the google image: http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Google-Apps.jpeg

I want after clicking on button that die G color changed from blue to red.

This is only an example.
Is much complex and its not possilbe to exchange the g for another g image.

What do you think?
Is it possible to reference parts of an image and change the color of these areas?

Comment: Please stop adding tags to the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want. Use several images or "build" one yourself with CSS. But keeping this image and changing its color on-the-fly won't be possible (unless you go really crazy)

Comment: i have a better example. Its something like this http://www.bodytrainer.tv/data/musclemaps/50/350.jpg. I want to highlight several parts under conditions. Goes that with CSS, what do you think is the best approach?

Comment: Its not possible to exchange images, because there are 25600000 different highlightings.